# Invoke method with arguments gives error

Tags: c#, reflection

I get an error `Parameter count mismatch.` when attempting to invoke a method in another class  on the line `val = (bool)method.Invoke(instance, args);`

The method only has a single argument and (I think) I'm passing a single argument as an object so not sure why I'm getting the error.

Please can someone advise what's wrong with my code?

```
class firstClass
{
    public bool MethodXYZ(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Wb, 
                    string debug_selectedOption)
    {
        object[] args = new object[] { Wb, debug_selectedOption };
        string methodToInvoke = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        return runGenericMethod(methodToInvoke, args);

    }
        private bool runGenericMethod(string methodToInvoke, object[] args)
        {
            bool val = false;
            string anotherClass = args[1].ToString();
            Type t = Type.GetType("ProjectXYZ." + anotherClass);
            MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(methodToInvoke);
            var constructorInfo = t.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            if (constructorInfo != null)
            {
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                val = (bool)method.Invoke(instance, args);
            }
        //........
            return val;
        }
}


class anotherClass
{
        public bool MethodXYZ(object[] args)
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the class name in the second position of the argument array?  Also, what are you actually passing into this function when you call it in your test?

Comment: I'm passing a webbrowser object and the method to invoke.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question.  What is the actual value of the string that you are passing, and what are the contents of the object array.

Comment: @Servy I've edited the Q to show how it is called. for example debug_selectedOption ="anotherClass"

Comment: So you'll always be calling methods with a reference to their own type as the first argument?  Also, the first argument is at index `0`, not index `1`.

Comment: args[0] is always the webbrowser, args[1] is always the method to run on the webbrowser. There will be multiple classes all with the same methods but will require specific code to navigate certain websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Invoke` takes an object array to support a variable number of parameters.  In your case you have just *one* parameter, which itself in an object array.  So you need to create an new object array whose only member is the original object array:

```
       val = (bool)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {args});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
val = (bool)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { args });
```

Second parameter of `Invoke` method takes `object[]` which is used to pass number of parameters ex:args[0] as first parameter, args[1] as second parameter and so on.

So when you pass object[] runtime assumes you're passsing multiple parameters, to make it clear to runtime you need to wrap inside another object[] which has only one element so it is passed as first parameter